# Doubts about spf record

Tags: smtp, spf

I went through several documentation how SPF records will be deployed, how it works against phishing email. Few things I couldn't understand those are below.  Please help me out here.

1. I have spf records for my domain "customer1.domain.com", but not my hosted company "domain.com" doesn't have it.
2. What is best practice, if my hosted company has multiple customers? If we set my relay domain SPF as "domain.com", and other customers can take advantage to generate spoof emails.
3. How should the receiver mta queries SPF? Any configuration is required in place to accept mails from domains have SPF. Since it accepts mails from all domains regardless of sender SPF. What action it takes, if any domain is not having SPF.

Comment: Maybe you format your question. Please verify this link on how to ask questions in Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It will help the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you send an email from "name@domain.com" then the SPF record located on "domain.com" takes effect.

Any mail server that you authorize to send an email with "name@domain.com" must be allowed to send under the SPF listed under "domain.com" or it will fail.

So the MTA looks up the SPF record located under domain.com, then checks the IP that sent the email and if their is a match, everything is good. If not, it fails SPF.

There are plenty of SPF tools you can use to check, one is by the one of the authors of SPF Scott Kitterman (http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html)

If you want to test a live email, you can send it to **mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com** and it will auto-respond with the results of the SPF test.

You can also read through this [complete email check up guide](https://www.zerobounce.net/guide-to-improve-inbox-and-delivery.html) to make sure you taken everything into account.